# Issue in sending email by Email campaign manager

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

I have installed email campaign manager in my Sitecore solution, I am sending email from ECM email are working fine, but if I want to send email on any event like Item deleted and Item saved this functionality not working for me.

I have create a rule under item saved and applied rule on that where the item template is xyz send "email message" email.
But I am not getting any email please let me know if I am missing something or I need to do any other steps.

-Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: Did you create a custom action to send the email? Is the code being hit (maybe add some logging)? Can you share the code for the action?

Comment: @jammykam I have not created any custom action "send specific email" action comes with Email Campaign manager itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new triggered message and activate it. In the rule, you will be able to select that triggered message.

Besides, make sure that the user has added the email address.

Comment: Yes, I am using triggered message only because in this action you can only select triggered message.

Comment: Please go to User Manager and make sure that the logged-in user has added the email address.

Comment: Yes, I am using my sitecore account.

Comment: Have you checked that the user has added an E-mail address in the User Manager?

Comment: Yes, user has Email address in Email field